# Spring Data Neo4j - How to connect a NodeEntity to the reference node 0?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I'd like to have a Neo4j graph where everything is connected to the reference node (node0). My idea was to connect node0 to a 'class type' node (rootNode) and then have all the nodes of a certain class connected to it. EG:

```
node0 --> unique RootUser --> many User
```

I'm using SpringNeo4j so I annotated RootUser and User with `@NodeEntity`. I have no idea of how to connect node0 to the RootUser in Spring though. I tried to add the following in the RootUser class but it does not work (referenceNode come from `neo4jTemplate.getReferenceNode()`):

```
@RelatedTo(type = "partition", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private Node referenceNode;
```

What's the best way to achieve this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 1):

What definitively will work is wiring the reference node to the spring data entities manually:

```
RelationshipType relationshipType = ...; // Whatever...

RootUser rootUser = new RootUser();
rootUser.persist();
neo4jTemplate.getReferenceNode().createRelationshipTo(rootUser.getPersistentState(), relationshipType);
```

You could try to declare a class for the reference node:

```
@NodeEntity
public class ReferenceNode {
}

@NodeEntity
public class RootUser {
    @RelatedTo(type = "partition", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private ReferenceNode referenceNode;

    public void setReferenceNode(ReferenceNode referenceNode) {
        this.referenceNode = root;
    }
}
```

...and load and set the reference node with:

```
ReferenceNode referenceNode = neo4jTemplate.load(neo4jTemplate.getReferenceNode(), ReferenceNode.class);
RootUser rootUser = new RootUser();
rootUser.persist();
rootUser.setReferenceNode(referenceNode);
```

This is untested and I'm not sure if the `neo4jTemplate.load()` part works.

Comment: neo4jTemplate.load() does not work:

org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' property not found for NodeImpl#0.
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:184)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:179)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:52)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:155)
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:107)